# Udev rule to alias device depending on USB port number

Tags: linux, udev, usb-drive

I want to write a UDEV rule that alias USB sticks depending on which port it is connected on my Raspberry Pi (which has 4 USB ports).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with the following rules, which can surely be improved:

```
KERNEL=="sd?" SUBSYSTEM=="block" SUBSYSTEMS=="usb" ATTRS{devpath}=="1.2" SYMLINK+="usb0"
KERNEL=="sd?" SUBSYSTEM=="block" SUBSYSTEMS=="usb" ATTRS{devpath}=="1.3" SYMLINK+="usb1"
KERNEL=="sd?" SUBSYSTEM=="block" SUBSYSTEMS=="usb" ATTRS{devpath}=="1.4" SYMLINK+="usb2"
KERNEL=="sd?" SUBSYSTEM=="block" SUBSYSTEMS=="usb" ATTRS{devpath}=="1.5" SYMLINK+="usb3"
```